# sending mail codeigniter don't work

Tags: codeigniter, email

I have my small function very simple and after email, I receive the following error message:

```
Severity: error --> Exception: Call to a member function from() on null
```

the function

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->helper('email');
    $this->email->from("soule.farouk@aef.info");
    $this->email->to('farouksoule@gmail.com');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();
    log_message('Error', $CI->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Comment: Did you try any of the answers you have not shown your config settings for email.

Answer (score 2):

You have `helper()` should be `library()`

```
public function index(){

    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from("soule.farouk@aef.info");
    $this->email->to('farouksoule@gmail.com');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();
    log_message('Error', $this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

---

Read [Email Class in Codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#using-the-email-library)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from("soule.farouk@aef.info");
    $this->email->to('farouksoule@gmail.com');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();
    log_message('Error', $CI->email->print_debugger());
  }
```

instead of helper use library
**For more details use this link**

[enter link description here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)